# Explicitly calling EGLIBC dynamic linker increases performance of ARM Linux executable

Tags: linux, performance, arm, embedded-linux

I see about a 5% performance increase if I explicitly invoke the dynamic linker:

```
 /lib/ld-linux.so.3 ./executable
```

LD_DEBUG=statistics has the same output.
LD_DEBUG=libs shows that the same DSOs are loaded
Even the output from LD_DEBUG=all is the same. (used diff)

This only happens if I use an EGLIBC sysroot with kernel 3.2.1
If I use the same EGLIBC sysroot but kernel 2.6.33 then performance does not change.

**What differences are there / could there be between explicitly calling the linker and implicitly?**

Comment: may be you don't add the time for invoking the linker? in any cases you should be able to profile this with some tools.

Comment: I run a test that checks performance during a fixed repeating window.

Comment: Please provide a test case, or reword to clarify what the question is.